# WebApp on iOS Homescreen - Navigating and Printing?

Tags: ios, web-applications, ios6, homescreen

I've added a webpage as WebApp to my iOS 6 Homescreen. But since there is no browser chrome after "start" I've some problems:
- How can I navigate within those websites launched from Homescreen?
- Can I provide special links (e.g. to Google Maps) from within a webpage that force iOS to start the real Safari browser?
- How can I access the print function from within such webpages - the normal safari print button isn't available ?
- Mail links doesn't work in webApps? (mailto:)  How can I make them work or force the webapp link from Homescreen to open in real Safari Browser?

Thanks, Konrad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to let users add your website/webpage to their homescreen and function as a web app, you need to build in your own controls from within the webpage the user is viewing.

Common web applications utilize a framework such as [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com) that builds in basic functions such as in-page navigation.